# Is there a penalty for having two block-producing (BP) nodes in a pool that try to mint a block in the same slot?

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-node, block-production, operator

Is there a penalty for having two block-producing (BP) nodes in a pool that try to mint a block in the same slot? For example, I'd like to bring up a new BP node in another region, but that results in two serving BP nodes for a brief moment, and just maybe that moment just happens to be the leader slot for the pool. What's the worst case scenario under this condition?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such penalty at the protocol level.

However, you will probably get called out on Twitter :)

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can you explain what actually happens in this scenario? My guess is that there's a "slot battle" but in this case the VRF key would be the same for both nodes, so I'm not sure how the protocol handles this situation.